# Perform REST call from background in android after fixed interval

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to Android, I want to know the most efficient way to perform a background operation which is a simple POST request with JSON Body which will be hit after a fixed interval. Which is best way, Intent Service Or Async Task.

Comment: From android 26, you have to use job scheduler. services are no longer an option to perform long running background operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a JobScheduler as below

```
 public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TestJobService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
        builder.setMinimumLatency(1 * 1000); // wait at least
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 1000); // maximum delay
        charging or not
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    }
```

Create the following receiver

```
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Util.scheduleJob(context);
    }
}
```

Register the receiver in the Android manifest for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` event.

```
<receiver android:name="MyStartServiceReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Create a JobService and add your code in to onStartJob

```
public class TestJobService extends JobService {
    private static final String TAG = "SyncService";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocalWordService.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(service);
        Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

For more details refer : [linkhere](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this link: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService

Please check my custom class example below. This will execute every 2 seconds.

```
class CustomThreadExecutor {

    private lateinit var scheduledExecutorService: ScheduledExecutorService
    private lateinit var scheduledFuture: ScheduledFuture<*>
    
    init {
        //Start Scheduler as required
        startScheduler()
    }

    
    fun startScheduler() {
        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2)

        scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                { tempImageFetch() }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }

    fun shutdownScheduler() {
        //Stop before exit the app or when necessary
        scheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow()

    }
    
    private fun tempImageFetch() {
        //TODO call API 
    }
}
```

Comment: will this work in background even after killing application and device reboot ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FirebaseJobDispatcher` for API level below and above Lollipop. Here is the github link:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

How to implement:

Add the following to your build.gradle's dependencies section:

```
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

Make a class for your job service:

```
    public class MyJobService extends JobService {
        @Override
        public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
            // Do some work here

            return false; // Answers the question: "Is there still work going on?"
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
            return false; // Answers the question: "Should this job be retried?"
        }
    }
```

Add this on Manifest:

```
<service
    android:exported="false"
    android:name=".MyJobService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Add this on your main activity onCreate method:

```
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));

    Bundle myExtrasBundle = new Bundle();
    myExtrasBundle.putString("some_key", "some_value");

    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
        // the JobService that will be called
        .setService(MyJobService.class)
        // uniquely identifies the job
        .setTag("my-unique-tag")
        // one-off job
        .setRecurring(false)
        // don't persist past a device reboot
        .setLifetime(Lifetime.UNTIL_NEXT_BOOT)
        // start between 0 and 60 seconds from now
        .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))
        // don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
        .setReplaceCurrent(false)
        // retry with exponential backoff
        .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
        // constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
        .setConstraints(
            // only run on an unmetered network
            Constraint.ON_UNMETERED_NETWORK,
            // only run when the device is charging
            Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING
        )
        .setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
        .build();

    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

If your application is for API level Lollipop and above, then you should use `JobScheduler` or `WorkManager`

For workmanager:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/

For JobScheduler:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Comment: The job is getting scheduled once, then I have to cancel the job again and then it cancels and then again onStartJob is called.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/131 Facing this issue

Comment: when onStartJob() is called, inside onStartJob() call this 
jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)this.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );
jobScheduler.cancelAll();